# Unable to use calculated properties with wmi

Tags: powershell, process, wmi

I'm trying to capture a few details regarding some processes on a windows server and as I understand it, performance counters are the way to go. Since the processes can be stopped/started at times, I wanted to make it a bit dynamic and give me the details of the running processes and with the commandline as well. Also, the process can have multiple instances running on the server with different command lines and process names. e.g. T-Process#1 , T-Process#2,T-Process#3.

Looking into WMI, I can't get everything from a single class and have to rely on two(Win32_Process and Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process). Since I can't use a single query to get details from two classes, I was going to use powershell and found a few posts about how to do so but I can't seem to make it work.

```
Get-CimInstance -Namespace root/cimv2 -Class Win32_process -Filter 'Name like "%T%"' -Property Name,Commandline,ProcessId | select-object Name,Commandline,ProcessId,@{Name='ProcessName';expression={(Get-CimInstance -CimSession (Get-CimSession | Where-Object ComputerName -eq $_.PSComputerName) -Namespace root/cimv2 -ClassName Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process -Filter 'IDProcess = $_.ProcessId' -Property Name).Name}}
```

I expected the code above to give me the process name(to be used in the performance counter),  and the name, commandline and I do get everything but not the process name which is a calculated property.

Any help on this would be great. I've tried a few different iterations of the expressions and nothing seems to work.

Thanks,
Karan

Comment: Change `-Filter 'IDProcess = $_.ProcessId'` to `-Filter "IDProcess = $($_.ProcessId)"` <-- otherwise you're requesting instances where the proc id is the verbatim string `$_.ProcessId`, which obviously fails because `$_.ProcessId` is not an integer

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you for the explanation, I was able to solve the issue.